# finding non-overlapping windows in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a pyspark dataframe with an `id` column and a time column (`t`) in seconds. For each `id` I'd like to group the rows so that each group has all entries that are within 5 seconds after the start time for that group. So for instance, if the table is:

```
+---+--+
|id |t |
+---+--+
|1  |0 |
|1  |1 |
|1  |3 |
|1  |8 |
|1  |14|
|1  |18|
|2  |0 |
|2  |20|
|2  |21|
|2  |50|
+---+--+
```

Then the result should be:

```
+---+--+---------+-------------+-------+
|id |t |subgroup |window_start |offset |
+---+--+---------+-------------+-------+
|1  |0 |1        |0            |0      |
|1  |1 |1        |0            |1      |
|1  |3 |1        |0            |3      |
|1  |8 |2        |8            |0      |
|1  |14|3        |14           |0      |
|1  |18|3        |14           |4      |
|2  |0 |1        |0            |0      |
|2  |20|2        |20           |0      |
|2  |21|2        |20           |1      |
|2  |50|3        |50           |0      |
+---+--+---------+-------------+-------+
```

I don't need the subgroup numbers to be consecutive. I'm ok with solutions using custom UDAF in Scala as long as it is efficient.

Computing `(cumsum(t)-(cumsum(t)%5))/5` within each group can be used to identify the first window, but not the ones beyond that. Essentially the problem is that after the first window is found, the cumulative sum needs to reset to 0. I could operate recursively using this cumulative sum approach, but that is too inefficient on a large dataset.

The following works and is more efficient than recursively calling cumsum, but it is still so slow as to be useless on large dataframes.

```
d = [[int(x[0]),float(x[1])] for x in [[1,0],[1,1],[1,4],[1,7],[1,14],[1,18],[2,5],[2,20],[2,21],[3,0],[3,1],[3,1.5],[3,2],[3,3.5],[3,4],[3,6],[3,6.5],[3,7],[3,11],[3,14],[3,18],[3,20],[3,24],[4,0],[4,1],[4,2],[4,6],[4,7]]]

schema = pyspark.sql.types.StructType(
  [
    pyspark.sql.types.StructField('id',pyspark.sql.types.LongType(),False),
    pyspark.sql.types.StructField('t',pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType(),False)
  ]
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [pyspark.sql.Row(*x) for x in d],
  schema
)

def getSubgroup(ts):
  result = []
  total = 0
  ts = sorted(ts)
  tdiffs = numpy.array(ts)
  tdiffs = tdiffs[1:]-tdiffs[:-1]
  tdiffs = numpy.concatenate([[0],tdiffs])
  subgroup = 0
  for k in range(len(tdiffs)):
    t = ts[k]
    tdiff = tdiffs[k]
    total = total+tdiff
    if total >= 5:
      total = 0
      subgroup += 1
    result.append([t,float(subgroup)])
  return result

getSubgroupUDF = pyspark.sql.functions.udf(getSubgroup,pyspark.sql.types.ArrayType(pyspark.sql.types.ArrayType(pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType())))

subgroups = df.select('id','t').distinct().groupBy(
  'id'
).agg(
  pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list('t').alias('ts')
).withColumn(
  't_and_subgroup',
  pyspark.sql.functions.explode(getSubgroupUDF('ts'))
).withColumn(
  't',
  pyspark.sql.functions.col('t_and_subgroup').getItem(0)
).withColumn(
  'subgroup',
  pyspark.sql.functions.col('t_and_subgroup').getItem(1).cast(pyspark.sql.types.IntegerType())
).drop(
  't_and_subgroup','ts'
)

df = df.join(
  subgroups,
  on=['id','t'],
  how='inner'
)

df.orderBy(
  pyspark.sql.functions.asc('id'),pyspark.sql.functions.asc('t')
).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `subgroup` column is equivalent to partitioning by `id, window_start` so maybe you don't need to create it.

To create `window_start` , I think this does the job :
`.withColumn("window_start", min("t").over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(asc("t")).rangeBetween(0, 5)))`

I'm not 100% sure about the behavior of rangeBetween.

To create `offset` it's just `.withColumn("offset", col("t") - col("window_start"))`

Let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks, but the issue with this is that the proposed `window_start` will split subgroups. Using time `[0,1,2,6,7]` and `rangeBetween(-5,0)` then 6 and 7 are in different subgroups (1 and 2 respectively).